# What is the Rush Hour puzzle with the most steps in its solution?

Tags: rush-hour

[Rush Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rush_Hour_%28board_game%29) is a well-known sliding-block puzzle in which you push cars around (each car moves horizontally or vertically) to let a red car escape the grid. The standard board is a 6x6 grid, with four 3x1 cars and twelve 2x1 cars available to place on the grid. Only the red car is ever placed horizontally on the third row, which is the escape row.

You cannot get the red car to escape with brute force; solving the gridlock sometimes requires some complicated and at other times counterintuitive manoeuvres. Generally, the more steps a solution has, the harder the puzzle is.

Level 40 in the original set sold by Binary Arts has a solution with 50 steps. But there must certainly be harder puzzles than that. What is the Rush Hour puzzle with the most possible steps in its solution?

Comment: The highest number of moves for the cards in the game, or the highest possible number of moves?

Comment: The highest possible number of moves.

Comment: @JoeZ. might I suggest you [edit] your clarification in to the question (and then flag all these comments as obsolete)?

Comment: On what board size? You can easily require `th(m*n)` moves solution on an `m*n` board by having a giant snake of 1x1 cars and only one free space.

Comment: Standard 6x6 board, maximum of twelve 2x1 cars and four 3x1 cars, only the red car is horizontal on the third row.

Comment: @JoeZ. be sure to edit that in please ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Done.

Comment: An (unachievable) upper bound can be determined by combinatorics: each of the 2x1 cars can have five positions and each of the 3x1 cars can have four, for a total of `(5^12)x(4^4) = 62 500 000 000` possible states for a particular board.

Comment: If you make a linear path out of the possible states, however, you will get a very long but boring and trivial game, a state labyrinth rather than a state maze.

Comment: @JanDvorak Where do you get your five and four position counts for the cars?  Since cars can be considered functionally equivalent under interchange (i.e., the game's choice of coloring is moot; the only distinguished car is the player-car), even the number-of-positions question is a variant on a tiling problem, and I don't think there's any simple formula even for the number of positions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Frédéric Servais has apparently done a lot of study of this problem, particularly his Masters' thesis, [*Finding hard initial configurations of Rush Hour with Binary Decision Diagrams*](http://code.ulb.ac.be/dbfiles/Ser2005mastersthesis.pdf).  For the 6x6 case without 'trucks' (3x1 pieces), he finds a maximum of 65 steps (plus the final move of the red car out); for the "full" 6x6 case, the maximum he finds is 92 steps, but it's not as clear to me from the skimming I've done that he has a proof of maximality for that position.  You can see diagrams of his top positions (note that move counts are off by 1 for these, since the results on this page count the final move of the escaping car as well) at http://cs.ulb.ac.be/~fservais/rushhour/ .

Comment: Although I'm very interested in the math, I'll mention for those strictly looking for *puzzles* that most of them in that paper (though not all) are right near the bottom, in Annex E.

Comment: And http://www.ulb.ac.be/di/algo/secollet/papers/crs06.pdf is quite related, though it doesn't *appear* to go into it in as much detail as the thesis you linked.